# Async|Await dentro de un loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async

Colegas, vengo con un problema que me tiene un poco frustrado.
Contextualizo el escenario: tengo un listado de **IDS** los cuales debo tomar uno por uno para realizar una llamada a una `API` y que ésta me devuelva un dato en particular.
Por motivos de estructura de la respuesta, dicha llamada debo hacerla dentro de un *loop* para así poder armar la respuesta como necesito.

El código sería el siguiente

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

let respuesta = []

array.forEach(async (item) => {
let uri = `url/${item.param}`

   await rp({
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      method: 'GET',
      uri: `${params.baseURI}${uri}`,
      json: true,
      headers: {...}
   }).then(res => {
      respuesta.push({
         ...
      })
   })
})
return respuesta
```

El problema pasa porque cuando retorna resultado me entrega el arreglo vacío; he intentado realizar funciones asíncronas pero no doy en el clavo. De hecho no he incluido los `async` y/o `await` porque prácticamente no me funcionan o fallan.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece!

Comment: que tal paulo podrias incluir tu codigo donde y como utilizas el async await??

Comment: Lo edito ahora!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y no podrías usar Promesas sin `async`/`await`? Por ejemplo algo así:

```js
let array = [ 1, 1.5, 2 ];

const promesas = array.map((item) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`esperado ${item} segundos`);
    }, item * 1000);
  });
});

// Promise.all recibe un array de Promise y ejecutará la función en then() cuando estén todas resueltas.
Promise.all(promesas).then(respuesta => {
  // respuesta es un array con los valores devueltos. Haz lo que quieras con respuesta.
  console.log(respuesta);
});
```

Con tu código quedaría algo de este estilo:

```js
// Función que hace las llamadas a las API. Recibe una lista de IDs y devuelve una promesa de que hará las llamadas.
function llamadasAPI(listaIDs) {
    const rp = require('request-promise');
    let respuesta = [];
    const promesas = [];

    listaIDs.forEach((item) => {
        let uri = `url/${item.param}`;
        const promesa = rp({
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            method: 'GET',
            uri: `${params.baseURI}${uri}`,
            json: true,
            headers: {...}
        });

        // Cada ID de la lista tiene su propia promesa de hacer una llamada a la API.
        promesa.then(res => {
            // Y cuando la promesa termine, ahí metes los datos que necesites.
            respuesta.push({
                ...
            });
        });

        // Guarda una lista de las promesas
        promesas.push(promesa);
    });

    // La función devuelve una promesa que se cumplirá una vez terminen todas las promesas del loop.
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    
        // Cuando terminen todas las promesas, se resolverá esta con el valor de respuesta.
        Promise.all(promesas).then(() => {
            resolve(respuesta);
        });
    });
}

// Llamamos la función y guardamos la promesa.
const promesaLlamadaAPI = llamadasAPI([ 1, 2, 3 ]);

promesaLlamadaAPI.then(respuesta => {
    // Lo que necesites hacer con los datos de las llamadas.
});
```

Las últimas líneas las puedes hacer sin `promesaLlamadaAPI` así:

```
llamadasAPI([ 1, 2, 3 ]).then(respuesta => {
    // Lo que necesites hacer con los datos de las llamadas.
});
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que como indique en la publicación, necesito realizar toda la operación dentro del ciclo. ¿Porqué? Por que dentro del loop hay un dato que debo incluir en la respuesta y que no se encuentra en el response del Promise =/

Comment: ¿Y no puedes pasar ese dato desde fuera después? Si es posible, quizá esa solución sea más sencilla que lo que buscas (que tampoco será imposible). Creo que el problema que tienes está relacionado con que las promesas no han terminado cuando haces `return respuesta`.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera he añadido código con una forma de resolver tu problema (o eso me parece jaja)

Comment: Excelente.. diste en el clavo, muy buena explicación ;)

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 const rp = require('request-promise');


async function test(item) {
    let uri = `url/${item.param}`;
    res = await rp({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        method: 'GET',
        uri: `${params.baseURI}${uri}`,
        json: true,
        headers: { ... }
    });
    return res;
}
async function test2(arr) {
    let respuesta = [];
    for await (const x in arr) {
        // espera hasta que rp devuelva algo
        res = await test(arr[x])
        respuesta.push(res);
    }
    return respuesta
}
```

Comment: Nada, sigue retornando primero la respuesta y después entra al ciclo =/

Comment: intenta ahora! para ver que tal

Comment: @Byro, mismo resultado colega :(

Comment: intetalo asi llamando a una funcion y esperando el resultado!

Comment: Tampoco.. adopte el código tal cual me indicaste y sigue pasando lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Paulo Urbano Rivera,

Prueba de esta forma, combinando Async/Await y Promise.al:

```
const sendRequest = async (array) => {
    try {
      //Recorremos todo el array y devolvemos un array de Promises sin resolver
      let promises = array.map(item => {
          let uri = `url/${item.param}`
          return rp({
              rejectUnauthorized: false,
              method: 'GET',
              uri: `${params.baseURI}${uri}`,
              json: true,
              headers: {...}
          })
      })

      let result = await Promise.all(promises) //Aqui resolvemos todas las Promises de una atacada

      return result

    } catch(e){
      console.error(e.message)
      return []
    }
}

let respuesta = sendRequest([1,2,3,4]) //Llamamos a la función con el array y obtenemos la respuesta
```

Creo que de esta forma seria más efectivo y rápido a la vez.

Pruébalo y ya nos comenta que tal te ha ido.

Un saludo

Comment: No me funcionó tu solución colega :( ... Sólo me retorno el estado de las promesas

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos el estado de las promesas con un console.log?